# Access column names of import(ed)-csv file that has no data rows without loading file again

Tags: powershell, csv

To display the header line of an imported csv file, I use:

```
$filename = ...
$table = @(import-csv $filename)
($table[0] | convertTo-csv)[1]
```

But if the csv file only contains the header and no subsequent data rows, the imported object turns out to be $null. I can't figured out how to get the property names of such an object (beside reading the file again as raw/ascii using something like Get-Content).

Comment: `Get-Content $filename |Where {$_ -notmatch '^#'} |Select -First 1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That is what I would can "reading the file again". I am looking for a solution to get the header from the already imported object. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: No, because there _is_ no "imported object" - `Import-Csv` parses the header, extracts the column names, and then _doesn't use them for anything_, because there isn't any data. So I guess the answer to your question is "no" :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Get-Content $filename -TotalCount 1
```

otherwise you can do it for list properties with your object :

```
$csv=import-csv "C:\temp\file3.txt"

$csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select Name
```

Comment: It's a working solution, but it is what I would can "reading the file again". I am looking for a solution to get the header from the already imported object.

Comment: 'Get-Member' on imported csv with only header and no data rows is the core of my problem. This yields an error. It says that it requires an object as input, thus suggesting that $csv is not an object here.

Answer (score -1):

In order to access the header line of a csv file with no data rows and not have to read it twice from the disk, *don't* `Import-csv` it straight away, but instead read the whole file as a text file using `Get-Content`, access the header as desired and then create a csv object using `ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```
$filename="<file>"

# read file as text:
$text = @(gc $filename )

    # do header line stuff as desired 
    # (works also on files with no data rows): 

    # evaluate delimiter
    $delimiter = @(",",";")[$text[0].Split(";").Length -gt 1] 

    # check if particular field exists
    $field_present = $text[0].Contains("<column header>")

# create the csv object
$table = (convertFrom-Csv $text -Delimiter $delimiter)
```